# Xcode 7 UI Testing - Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Timeout waiting to launch Target Application

Tags: xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm running close to 30 Xcode 7 UI test scripts and my tests fail 10 - 15 scripts in with this error:

```
    Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Timeout waiting to launch Target Application 0x1004c5400
<unknown>:0: error: -[Name_Tests test_FormName] : UI Testing Failure - Timeout waiting to launch Target Application 0x1004c5400
    t =    30.59s     Tear Down
Test Case '-[Name_Tests test_FormName]' failed (30.599 seconds).
```

Then, all my scripts after this failure will have this error message:

```
Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - App state is still not terminated
<unknown>:0: error: -[Name_Tests test_VideoName] : UI Testing Failure - App state is still not terminated
```

There is no problem with the individual scripts because they run fine on their own.  Any ideas on a fix?

EDIT: The device i'm testing on is an iPad Mini on iOS 9.1 and it crashes on the startup of the test

Comment: Does the error occur in the same step? If so, what is the step? Also, what platform are you testing against?

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I'm testing on an iPad on iOS 9.1 (device, not simulator) and the error occurs during the start up of the test

Comment: What about the assertion failure? When/how does that occur?

Comment: @JoeMasilotti It looks like this is an Xcode issue.  Thanks for your help.  Btw, your XCTest Reference documentation helped me tons when I was getting started in this.  You're a godsend.

Comment: Thanks! Glad you got it all sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is XCode bug. What is your XCode version? Have you seen https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13234 ?

Comment: No I haven't!  This is exactly the same issue I'm having.  I guess you're right, it is an Xcode issue.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: one of the solutions given on that link is to upgrade to Xcode 7.2. If thats not an option, any alternatives we know of?

Comment: @Vish unfortunately, i do think so.

Comment: @Vish Upgrading to 7.2 gives more errors for me.  They're new error messages, but much more frequent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325297/xcode-ui-tests-are-failing-because-of-xcapplicationstaterunningactive-on-physica

Comment: I added an app.terminate() and then cleaned/rebuilt my Xcode project, restarted, reconnected my device and reran the test - which for all of Friday worked perfectly. Will need to keep an eye out for a relapse of the issue.