# Xcode UI Tests are failing because of XCApplicationStateRunningActive on physical device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

In my app I'm adding some UI tests. With one test method everything works perfectly, but when I added second method, the test is failing because of the following error:
[image]

I feel like [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch]; doesn't terminate the app as it suppose to.

EDIT 1:

I also noticed, if I press home button on my physical device after test finishes, I can see 2 instances of the app still running on the background. And if I try to start the tests again I get the message in Xcode that it can not start running the app because the app null is still running. This is frustrating :(

Does anyone have a clue or had a similar issue?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here... keen to know if you find an answer. More info - even with many tests, it's always the second one that produces this error (even after changing the order of tests). Have you tried creating tests in a blank iOS app?

Comment: No, didn't try with the empty app...but I need these tests working with my current app :)

Comment: Can I suggest everyone with the same issue submits a bug report to Apple? If it's really a problem for anyone, using a 'technical support incident' has escalated the problem into the hands of an engineer on the relevant team in the past for me, could be worth a shot.

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps helpful debugging info: I have this same problem when running my UI tests on Travis. Initially the first test passed, and all subsequent tests failed. I suspect the Travis instances are headless, causing issues for UI tests. I noticed that my app had some constraint issues with very small windows, and, by fixing issues with small displays, I was able to pass more, though not all, of my UI tests on Travis. Are headless OSX instances possible? Do they have a very low resolution or other limitations?

Comment: My radar on this has been closed as a dupe of 23920068. Also see [this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/97050) on the Apple forums.

Comment: forced quit the simulator and ran tests again fixed the issue for me

Comment: I feel like todays xcode update Version 7.2.1 (7C1002) fixed this issue, can anyone who had this issue too confirm?

Comment: I have the same issue, but while running tests on CI server. Also it appears randomly on test start, but never, when I run test from XCode. XCode 7.3 beta 5 didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a bug report and have been asked to test on Xcode 7.3 beta 3. It is fixed!
You can check my radar 24524204‌ that is now closed as resolved.

Comment: yes, I know, If you read my comment from  Feb 3 at 20:36  you would see that :)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the app isn't being torn down correctly after the first test is completed. Try explicitly killing the app in your tear down method.

```
- (void)tearDown {
    [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] terminate];
    [super tearDown];
}
```

Comment: I've the same problem and have tried this and dose not solve the problem for me. I am running on device and using xcode 7.2.

Comment: Same thing is happening for me too as well ever since I updated to 7.2

Comment: @JamesGoe tried that, this way it shows both tests failing

Comment: Same thing here. Even killing the app does not sets the proper app stated before the next test begins.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to 7.3 beta resolved this issue for me. It definitely seems to be related to the teardown functionality.